# extract information from a json file with jq

Tags: python, json, excel, parsing, jq

I tried to get the Id: if the name of the plant is corn-1 and the price is 20 then print the Id

```
{
    "Id":  "Category-1",
    "Plants":
    [
        {
            "Name":  "corn-1",
            "Price":  "20"
        },
        {
            "Name":  "corn-2",
            "Price":  "10"
        },
        {
            "Name":  "corn-3",
            "Price":  "5"
        },
    
    ]
}

cat plants.json | jq -C 'select(.Plants[].Name=="corn-1" and .Price=="20").Id
```

but nothing is printed out. I should get Category-1.
Any ideas please ?

Comment: Are there any other Id? Is this an array of objects or how is the file structured in reality?

Comment: If **at  least one** (`any`) of the array items matches the conditions: `select(any(.Plants[]; .Name=="corn-1" and .Price=="20")).Id`

Comment: Yes this is the all file and the id is unique

Comment: I don't understand. You want to get the Id if the data are there and nothing if the data aren't there?

Comment: Exactly @choroba

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
jq -C 'select(.Plants[] | (.Name == "corn-1" and .Price == "20")).Id'
```

The problem was you used `.Price` in the context of the top object, so it never matched.

If there are several matches in one Plants, the Id will be printed multiple times. To get it only once, you can use

```
jq -C 'select(.Plants | any(.Name == "corn-1" and .Price == "20")).Id'
```

Comment: Yeah it's working, thanks dude!

Comment: jq -C 'select(.Plants | any(.Name == "corn-1" and .Price == "20")).Id' why don't you use .Plants[] ?

Comment: `any` operates on an array, not its members.